# How to get google-services.json without migrating to firebase

Tags: java, php, android

Currently i am working on an android project.
So im using Google Cloud Messaging for push notifications 
and i have to add another app to `gcm` so i want `google-services.json` file  for gcm service but now google is saying **first i have to register on firebase and  migrate it and then i can get** `google-services.json` file. The reason why i don't want firebase base is that i have to mod all webservice according to firebase. Is there any other way for doing this ?

I have so many methods like this.

```
public function send_message($gcm_id,$details){

$reg_token = array($gcm_id);

$msg =array("message"=>$details);

//Creating a new array fileds and adding the msg array and registration token array here 
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $reg_token,
    'data'          => $msg
);

//Adding the api key in one more array header 
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key= MY_API_KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
); 

//Using curl to perform http request 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );


//Getting the result 
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

//Decoding json from result 
$res = json_decode($result);


//Getting value from success 
$flag = $res->success;

//if success is 1 means message is sent \
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
if($flag == 1){
    //Redirecting back to our form with a request success 
     $response["error"] = false;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Message SuccessFully Sent Check Your Device";
     echo json_encode($response);

}else{
    //Redirecting back to our form with a request failure 
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Eror Occured";

    echo json_encode($response);
}  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm migrating to firebase only to download google-services.json without changing anything on webservice and android project, and it's work

Comment: android and webservice still using gcm